# MySQL structure of website with parent and child topics

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql

I am building a website that has a parent/child structure for various topics. (Too explain it a bit more, it actually has 4 levels, so: `parent < child < 2nd child < 3rd child`) Currently I have a table for each level in MySQL. Each child has a row that refers to the parent's id and primary key. The issue that I am having is that i see no way to create a list that shows the sub topics like that shown below:

```
Food 
    Fruit  
        Red  
           Cherry  
        Yellow  
           Banana  
    Meat  
        Beef  
        Pork
```

I have thought about using a single hierarchical table like that on: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ that i know can output a list like that.

However, the issue with that is that table could easily have millions of posts (assuming this gets of the ground) and a recursive function that sorts through it every time a page is requested seems like it would take a long time to load.

Although i recognize it is not a great question and answer site, I was wondering if anyone knew how Yahoo Answers stores their categories and subcategories as it seems similar to what I need to do. Are there any sites that have a category/subcategory database that anyone can provide information about?

If I want to have a list like that above, would I have to single hierarchical table (either adjacent list model or modified preorder tree structure) or could I just use php, sql, and javascript to create a list like that with what i currently have; that is 4 tables each for each level of child?

Comment: Why don't you just use a CMS like Drupal? Seems odd to build that from scratch.

Comment: I'm interested in this topic too. Just an idea: what about storing the "level" where is placed the topic? It could help searching "up" the tree

Comment: @Sebi, i suppose that is a possible solution, however I'm hoping to have it all manageable locally without having to use another product to deliver my product.

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL That could work, but it seems like it would still take a long time to sort all of that data.

Comment: I have a similar system, built from scratch (if I understand your question). I have 'parent' links, with 'child' links linked to parents, and 'grandchild' links linked to the child links. All links are in the same table, but I added a level field (parents: level=0, child: level=1 etc), and added a link_parent field. The link_parent field for child links would be set to their relevant parents unique ID. Hope that made sense!

Comment: @PhilCross thats like what Fire-Dragon-Dol suggested as well. I suppose with a level row i could have more control over what is outputted on the website. Is your table adjacent list model or modified preorder tree structure? (if you arent sure check out the link below) http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: Its the adjacent list model, it only has around 300 records, but it works very well, and I use 1 table to manage the links on 7 separate sites.

Comment: @ryno: A good idea (or maybe not, I don't know) could be this: after adding the level-column, when you need to "fetch" the parents of this row you do a first query to get the level-column, then you build through php a long join query so that the database will hopefully optimize it. I'm still looking for a way to do this at same time only with one query on all columns, I don't have an idea at the moment, although that article seems pretty interesting

Comment: @PhilCross, thanks ill look into that for my site.

Comment: Yeah to do it based on the level column first could cut down on the time required to get information.

Comment: @ryno: I'm reading the article: why don't you use the approach suggested there?Seems really interesting.

Comment: Mh maybe I understood, you are forced to update whole table when you insert a new category.

Comment: i probably will use one of the methods on there, however if my site is currently built so you can go to section.php/id=1 for the first type of data, category.php/id=2 for the second type of category in the parent. I would like to keep that structure for ease of navigation as well as keeping mysql tables smaller

Comment: @PhilCross, if you put something as an answer ill give you the points.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need tables for each level. You need recursive relationship based tables that will allow you to create 'n' number of levels.

Here is a simple concept, Consider a table with the following fields:

```
id(primary key) - item_name - parent_id(foreign key {default=0})
```

Where:
parent_id refers back to the same tables id column.

example:

```
id - name - parent_id
1 - ABC - 0
2 - XYZ - 0
3 - ABX - 1
4 - JKK - 1
5 - KHM - 3
6 - KHJ - 5
```

here, ABC is at level 0 (i.e. they got no parent), but ABX is the parent of KHM while also the child of ABC.